# how to load multiple q scripts at start up of q session

Tags: kdb

I know how to load a single script when starting q session: 
q myscript1.q -p 9001

what if I have two scripts both of which I want to load simultaneously at startup:
q myscript1.q myscript2.q -p 9001 doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you want to load them as simultaneous, distinct processes?

Answer (score 2):

Make use of QINIT, detailed here https://code.kx.com/q/basics/environment/.
It will load a script for you, and in that you can do as you please

```
// add the load of your file to a startup script
cat start.q
\l a.q
\l b.q

// export QINIT to be your startup script
export QINIT=start.q

// start q, it will load start.q, which will in turn load you startup scripts (a.q and b.q)
q
```

Answer (score 0):

load one of the scripts at the start of the other.

eg. in the first line of myscript.q

```
\l myscript2.q
```

then when you run

```
q myscript.q -p 9001
```

both scripts will be loaded in your q session